# Auto numbering based on repeating cells

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I need help auto numbering a spreadsheet that has submissions with inventors but some submissions have multiple people listed, but need to be numbered the same.

e.g.:

```
No.     Count     Name
0011    1         Joe
0012    0.5       Sam
0012    0.5       Alex
0013    1         Ryan
```

The `Count` is determined by how many people the submission is divided up against. The `Number` represents the submission, so #0012 is Sam's and Alex's so they need to be numbered the same. I'm hoping there's an easy way I can number the worksheet rather than going and numbering each one individually. I need a formula that will auto-number the `Count` and `Name` records depending on if the `Count` repeats.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please explain your question a little better and maybe add a screenshot so that it is easy to understand.

Comment: Is the count a given number, and can it be used to determine the number?

Comment: It doesn't appear that your submissions have any naming or numbering system that can be used to identify duplicates. Is there something missing here?

Comment: Sorry, so the count would be how many people the submission is divided up against. The Number represents the submission, so #0012 is Sam's and Alex's so they need to be numbered the same. I'm hoping there's an easy way I can number the worksheet rather than going and numbering each one individually. So I need a formula that will auto number depending on if the Count repeats. If that makes sense?...

Comment: I know many people like to use Excel, but your use case would be better served using a database tool such as Microsoft Access. One table would be for invention no. and the other table would be inventor name. You would join the two tables by using the invention no.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set your first number manually with the formula below.

```
=TEXT(11,"0000")
```

In the next cell below, enter this formula and fill down the column:

```
=IF(AND(B3=B2,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)<1/B3),TEXT(A2,"0000"),TEXT(A2+1,"0000"))
```

[image: screen shot of example sheet]

This works on the idea that the only time you don't want to augment the number is when the count is the same as the previous record and the number above isn't already listed the appropriate number of times. (The appropriate number of times is equal to `1/Count`.) This second condition is necessary because of cases like rows 10 through 13 in the example, where groups of the same size follow each other in the table.

Comment: Excellll posted this while I was writing my answer.  His approach is more elegant than the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that Sam and Alex are associated with the same submission and not each co-submitters of different projects?  You need some basis for grouping.  The reliable way to do it would be to add a column that is unique to the submission, like the submission title, to serve as a unique identifier.  You sort the list on that.  Then increment the numbering if the unique ID is different from the previous row.

For example, assume col A is the unique ID, B is your No., C is the count, and D is Name, and what you are showing as the first row of data (0011) is row 2.  A general formula that you could copy for all cells in B (based on B2), would be:

```
=if(row()=2,1,if(a2=a1,b1,b1+1))
```

You can get fancy with formatting if you want to force leading zeros.

It is not good practice, but if you are manually ensuring that the list is sequential and this is all you have to work with, you could do something like this: Assume Col A is your No., B is Count, C is Name.  Add a new column D (which could be hidden).  Again row 2 is the first data row.  A general formula for all cells in D (based on D2), would be:

```
=if(b2=1,1,if(b1=1,b2,if(row()=2,b2,d1+b2)))
```

This identifies when each submission group ends in case you have several sequential multiple submissions.

The general formula for your No. (based on A2), would be:

```
=if(row()=2,1,if(d1=1,a1+1,a1))
```

Again, you can format to force leading zeros.

Edit: Recognize that relying only on the sequence in which you entered the data to do the numbering (my second example and Excellll's solution), is risky if there is any chance that the data sequence could change, for example, by accidentally sorting the data. The numbering logic would fall apart and give you incorrect results.  Incorporating a unique ID for each submission provides a foolproof way to recover (simply sort on the ID).

Comment: Excellll, where do I find instructions on formatting answers (like the vertical bar you added to the formula lines), embedding screen grabs or images, etc.?

Comment: When you open the edit window, there is a red/pink question mark at the upper right of the text window. Click it for markdown editing help.